# Audio Driver has 'Location: Unknown' and isn't working even though windows xp says it functions fine

Tags: windows-xp, audio, drivers

I have a dell latitude d830 with windows XP professional. I'm using the built-in speakers. It's definitely not a hardware problem as when I switch my HDDs and boot into Windows 7 the audio works fine. When I try to bring up volume settings it says no speakers found. I have the drivers but XP says the drivers have an unknown location. Please help. If you need any further info then feel free to ask.

EDIT: I have some more info and images.

-I am on Windows XP Professional with Service Pack 2 with version 2002

-I have an Intel Core2 Duo T7700 @2.40GHz

-3.49 GB of RAM

-Physical Address Extension (whatever that means)

-Instead of asterisk noise, computer does a default beep (not anything to do with windows) BIOS?

[IMAGES]:
[Audio Drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDox0.png)
[Media Player Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJ3XL.png)
[No Audio Device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7fwf.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: XP can no longer  be updated, patched, or fixed.

Comment: Has XP ever worked on this computer? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc No, we did have an installation with an account but we couldn't log in (as the 'administrator account' hack had a password set to it) so we couldn't test if it worked.

Comment: Seems like your drivers don't work for XP. Where have you found them?

Comment: @harrymc They are all default with my Dell D830, I do have a disk with a few backup drivers but I don't know which is which.

Comment: See Dell's [Latitude D830 support](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/latitude-d830/drivers). Set Category to Audio and download the driver for your audio component.

Answer (score -1):

Just a case of re-installing the audio driver. I have a CD-ROM with backed up drivers. I went through them all and found an audio one. Installed it. Went into the audio config app - SigmaTel - via control panel and checked the first checkbox to disable this beep the PC would make instead of the asterisk.

Also as @harrymc said, you can go to [this link](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-uk/product-support/product/latitude-d830/drivers) and find the driver called 'SIGMATEL STAC 92XX C-Major HD Audio, v.5.10.0.5515_RC22-WHQL, A11' and download it that way. I was just lucky enough to have it on a backup CD.